# Java XX command line options unrecognized (e.g: -XX:+UseStringDeduplication, -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis)

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to specify some GC tuning options on the command line and for some reason keep running into the 'Unrecognized option' error.

> java -Dproperty1=value -Dproperty2=value2 -cp ./some/jarFile1.jar:./some/jarFile2.jar  com.xyz.ClassFile -c /path/to/a/file –XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseStringDeduplication -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200

returns

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.commons.cli.UnrecognizedOptionException: Unrecognized option: -XX:+UseStringDeduplication

Same thing with the `XX:MaxGCPauseMillis` option if I removed StringDeduplication.

Running Java 8, version info:

```
java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)
```

Any clues appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be careful when entering characters. The dash before your `–XX:+UseG1GC` is not the [ASCII hyphen/minus](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/002D/index.htm), but the [“En Dash”](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm) character.

If you look closely in the browser view of your question, you might notice a difference in length and vertical position, e.g. when comparing with the `-XX:+UseStringDeduplication` option. However, that depends on the actual font and it is not unlikely that both characters look the same in the editor/console where you entered the command line.

For java command line options, you have to always use the ASCII hyphen/minus character (`U+002D`) which should be the default when pressing <kbd>-</kbd> on an ordinary keyboard.

Comment: Now, is that a "simple typographical error" or not ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat: yeah, but my explanation didn’t fit into a comment. Closing the question still is an option, though… Well, thinking about it, it isn’t a *simple* typographical error as most keyboard layouts don’t support the En Dash directly. Mac, perhaps?

Comment: @Holger good eye for detail and great response. I have replaced the En Dash with the ASCII hyphen, and had to move the -XX options at the start of the syntax, which worked. Thanks!

Comment: @ideaz Just out of curiosity: any idea how that En Dash got there in the first place? Your keyboard is a gift from your mother-in-law who hates you?

Comment: @GhostCat haha, total user error - probably a bad copy pasta from a GC tuning article I was reading earlier.